# Questions that basically ask TWP to function as someone's Google Assistant

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'd like to get everyone's thoughts on how questions like this fit against guidelines on this site:

[Agreement between employee and employer for use of personal equipment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/131991/agreement-between-employee-and-employer-for-use-of-personal-equipment)

Although the larger topic might make for interesting material, the literal question being asked feels to me like something that can just be googled, and doesn't really need to be posted on The Workplace:

> Has anyone seen a boiler plate version of something like this that I could take and modify?

My first reaction was vote to close, but I'm not really sure any of the default close reasons fit well. That lead me to pause and consider why I was assuming it should be closed in the first place.

Comment: I have also noticed that such shopping-list questions tend to gather link-only (as it is the case for this post) and poor answers in general... thus, why they need to be edited or if not possible closed

Comment: Maybe a better question is "Does anyone have any *experience* of X". That is likely to attract people with expertise or at least experience. Neither of those is available easily on Google.

Comment: I would have thought for questions like those, the "What have you already researched and dismissed?" comment would crop up.

Comment: It's not a shopping-list question, [revision #4 by DavidK](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/131991/4) fixed that. So this post is now obsolete. It's much better to fix a fixable question than lobby people to close/delete/declare it offtopic. It's now on-topic and useful. Btw your title is very non-neutral and leading... many of us would not share your reaction even to the original wording. I always try to see if there's some kernel of generalizable, on-topic.

Answer (score 7):

As is, this type of question would fall under the category of a [Shopping List Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/260884).

> Questions that ask for a list of things, like "is there a tool that
>   does x on platform y?" or "what is the best abc for my problem?" are
>   usually regarded not a good fit on Stack Overflow, even if they are
>   perfectly programming related, and often not a good fit for Stack
>   Exchange sites too.

As this type of question is fairly open-ended with no single correct answer, I usually vote to close as being opinion-based.

Alternatively, you can try to edit the question into a form that is no longer just asking for sample forms, (though personally I'm not sure exactly how to fix this one without trying to infer too much from the OP).

Comment: These questions usually have an easy fix: Instead of _can u pls give me teh forms_, they can be edited to focus on _what are the important things to be set out in this form_ and take it from there

Comment: @rath I think that comment is very valuable. It's more helpful than just closing the question, but still (hopefully) allows you to preserve the OP's intent. I am usually very hesitant to edit questions in a way that actually changes the question (vs, say, editing for grammar) so maybe the best way to implement would be to suggest in comments that the OP make those edits if they see fit, in order to improve the question.

Comment: @dwizum I went ahead and made the edit. If the OP strongly disagrees, they can always roll it back (and be closed). The question looks like it's on the verge of closing, so we may want to keep an eye out in case it needs to be reopened.